# Building NSF/NTF using command line (Notes Domino Designer)

Tags: command-line, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I am trying to build nsf/ntf via command line, I am trying to follow this link [Headless Designer](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Headless_Designer_Wiki#+Command+Line+Building+of+NSFs+) . Every thing seems in the documentation very obvious.
  But even if I have added 'DESIGNER_AUTO_ENABLED=true' in notes.ini the command explained in the documentation doesn't seems working.

Error:Command or Option is not recognized.

Hope someone has tried this.
Any kind of advice and suggestion are appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Ajit please edit your question and add the exact call you used. Follow instructions leaves people guessing. It might be a problem or a misunderstanding

Comment: For first step just try to replace path to your On-Disk-Project in sample command designer.exe -RPARAMS -vmargs -Dcom.ibm.designer.cmd="true,true,Discussion.nsf,importandbuild,C:\XPageApps\Discussion\.project,Discussion.nsf" . Also use notes.ini without password, it makes life easier.